# Why is Al2O3 so popular in plasmonics?

Tags: electronics, solar-cells, optical-materials, plasmon

I've tried to find my own solution for this question and found out that

1. It is cheap
2. It is an insulator
3. It efficiently absorbs UV

Are there more properties that makes it so popular?

Answer (score 0):

It's a crystal. It guides energy with less dissipation then do this other materials.